# good way to design

Tags: java, apache, httpresponse

I would like to have the following method which returns `HttpResponse`. But at the same time I do not want to initialize `HttpResponse` to `null`.
Which is a good way to do, adding `throws` for the method or adding `try/catch` blocks with `HttpResponse` initialized to `null`.
`HttpResponse` is an interface so initializing this doesn't make any sense.
I am thiking of adding getters/setters for `HttpResponse` declaring this as a member variable.

Ideas are appreciated.

```
public HttpResponse executeRestClientServiceCall(final HttpUriRequest request)
    {
        // Verifier;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try
        {
            httpResponse = client.execute(request);
            return httpResponse;
        }
        catch (final ClientProtocolException e)
        {
        }
        catch (final IOException e)
        {
        }
        return httpResponse;
    }
```

Comment: Interfaces can be null, and it makes exactly as much sense for them to be null as a class.

Comment: And *never* use uncommented unhandled exception handlers in your code.

Comment: This question may be better asked at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you should look at spring's RestTemplate. As long as you're re-inventing wheels, you should at least find out what features and drawbacks existing wheels have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not catch the exception at this point. Not at all. This makes your code much simpler. What you have to do though is to release all the resources that you used, and do so properly. This is the code to do that:

```
@Nonnull
public HttpResponse executeRestClientServiceCall(HttpUriRequest request) throws IOException {
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);
  try {
    // ... other code ...
  } finally {
    HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
      entity.getContent().close();
    }
  }
  return httpResponse;
}
```

At this point you cannot decide what to do with the exception, so the best choice is to just let it slip through to the caller. Maybe he knows what to do with it.

Throwing an exception gives the caller more possibilities than just returning `null`.

Considering your other questions:

> But at the same time I do not want to initialize HttpResponse to null.

This is good, since you can write your code so that the variable always holds a proper object. See the code above.

> Which is good way to do adding throws for the method or adding try/catch blocks with httpResponse initialized to null.

I answered it above. The good way is to add a `throws` clause for the method.

> I am thiking of adding getters/setters for HttpResponse declaring this as a member variable.

Don't do that. The `HttpResponse` is an object that typically has a very short life span. It should always be stored in a local variable, and when the method returns, there is no need to keep it. This is different from the `HttpClient`, which you should store in a field of a class, so you can add a connection pool later if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Roland's answer of not trying to handle the exceptions at that level. It would be better to surface it to the caller so they can react appropriately. Think of the case where the response might fail, the caller could retry with an altered request. This is different than the case of the server timing out or not responding where you would probably not want to re-attempt a request.

If you do have to handle the Exceptions at that level you are trying, try the following code; it will eliminate the need for initializing things to null...

```
public HttpResponse executeRestClientServiceCall(final HttpUriRequest request)
{
    final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try
    {
        return client.execute(request);
    }
    catch (final ClientProtocolException e)
    {
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
    }
    return null;
}
```

This simple change also eliminates the need for the variable and makes the intent of the method clearer. The only reason you would use a variable, initialized to null, and then set differently in different branches of logic is if you are trying to remove multiple break points of the method. It is sometimes good to only have a single exit point of any method, but from the looks of it, you weren't aiming for this in the first place, so what I have suggested should work just fine.